# Disable time picker in Datetime picker

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datepicker, datetimepicker

I want to disable the time picker in datetime picker.I am using some parameters like  pickTime: false and format: "dd MM yyyy" .But no use..i'm using from this http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
             format: "dd MM yyyy" 
        });
    </script>
```

Plzz give a solution

Comment: Use format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'

Comment: time picker is working using this

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137720/disable-time-in-bootstrap-date-time-picker

Comment: thank u all..I got answer using   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'});

Answer (score 1):

You can pick date with

```
$('#datetimepicker1').val()
```

or

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data('date')
```

This only gives the date value

> Possible Duplicate of [How to get the value of the date using Bootstrap Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681875/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-date-using-bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 1):

You did some wrong in object passing into the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: "dd MM yyyy" 
        });      
    });
</script>
```

Comment: did you add `Moment.js` file? See the [Installing](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/)

Answer (score 1):

Better to use this to get only Date and you also have multiple Options with it

Have a look at this

[Bootstrap DatePicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=component&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

Answer (score 1):

It was your format string.  'yyyy' does not exist.  It is 'YYYY' instead.

Also, dd would have gotten you the days like this:  Su, Mo, Tu, ...

You probably wanted 01, 02, 03,...

Here's the documentation on the format:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```

As answered by Celt in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28542910/2295862